# Why am I getting a random "Communication Link Failure" in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I had no issues last week running queries on our remote SQL Server database, but as of this morning I am continually struggling to keep the error below from populating when running the query from a specific device. I'll try to run the query through SSMS with no luck.

> OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "SERVER_NAME" returned message "Communication link failure".
>
> Msg 10060, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
> TCP Provider: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

This issue occurs with a specific computer on the network, but all other computers on the same network accessing the same remote DB don't have an issue. I've checked firewall settings to ensure outgoing access to 1433. It randomly worked about an hour ago for all of 10 minutes then went back to throwing the error.

I can connect to the remote DB through SSMS, and I can run queries on the DB from within SSMS so long as I'm running the query directly on the DB, but when I run the query from the local computer through linked server on this one computer, it tries to run for 24 seconds then gives the same OLE DB provider error. I can follow the same steps on another computer with no issue.

Comment: Have you run a pings and trace route when the error occurs, are there any network switches involved you could test bypassing?

Comment: Working on running the ping now, but there is one cellular router but it can't be bypassed because it is our gateway to the internet to get access to the remote DB.

Comment: Like right now it's randomly working again on the troubled device! I dont understand

Comment: That's a network issue.